# Multiple plots with high-level plotting functions, especially plot.rqs()

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot two regression summaries side-by-side with one centered title. Each regression summary is generated by `plot.rqs()` and amounts to a set of 9 plots.

I've tried using `par(mfrow=c(1,2))` already, but as I learnt from Paul Murrel's (2006) book, high-level functions like `plot.rqs()` or `pairs()` save the graphics state before drawing and then restore the graphics state once completed, so that pre-emptive calls to `par()` or `layout()` can't help me. `plot.rqs()` doesn't have a 'panel' function either.

It seems that the only way to achieve the result is to modify the `plot.rqs()` function to get a new function, say `modified.plot.rqs()`, and then run

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
modified.plot.rqs(summary(fit1))
modified.plot.rqs(summary(fit2))
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

From there I might be able to work out how to add an overall title to the image using `layout()`. Does anyone know how to create a `modified.plot.rqs()` function that could be used in this way?

Thanks

Comment: You can look at `plot.rqs` (or `plot.summary.rqs`) and remove the offending `par` calls.

Comment: Yes I tried, but I ended up with the error message: "Error in x$tau : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors". I thought it was something I was doing wrong :(

Answer (score 3):

You can patch a function as follows:
use `dput` and `capture.output` to retrieve
the code of the function, as a string;
change it as you want (here, I just replace each occurrence of `par`
with a function that does nothing);
finally evaluate the result to produce a new function.

```
library(quantreg)
a <- capture.output(dput(plot.summary.rqs))
b <- gsub("^\\s*par\\(", "nop(", a)
nop <- function(...) {}
my.plot.summary.rqs <- eval(parse(text=b))
```

Comment: Wow. That is fairly slick, Vincent. I've always just copied console ouput to the screen or an editor.

Comment: @DWin: But it is not always sufficient,
for instance if the function uses non-exported functions
(probably easy to fix with `environment(f) <- ...`),
or, worse, if what you want to modify is in a non-exported function.

Comment: Thanks Vincent! When I run it on the example(plot.rqs) fit 'fm' I get this error message: Error in x$tau : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: There are two functions: `plot.rqs` and `plot.summary.rqs`,
which work on objects of type `rqs` and `summary.rqs` respectively.
If you mix them up, you get the error message you mention.
The following works: `my.plot.summary.rqs(summary(fm))`.

Answer (score 3):

First we generate an example object, `fm` .  Then we copy `plot.rqs` and use `trace` on the copy to insert `par <- list` at top effectively nullifying any use of `par` within the function.  Then we do the same with `plot.summary.rqs`.  Finally we test it out with our own `par`:

```
library(quantreg)
example(plot.rqs) # fm to use in example

# plot.rqs
plot.rqs <- quantreg::plot.rqs
trace("plot.rqs", quote(par <- list), print = FALSE)

# plot.summary.rqs
plot.summary.rqs <- quantreg::plot.summary.rqs
trace("plot.summary.rqs", quote(par <- list), print = FALSE)

# test it out
op <- par(mfrow = c(2, 2))

plot(summary(fm))
plot(fm)
title("My Plots", outer = TRUE, line = -1)

par(op)
```

EDIT: added `plot.summary.rqs`.

Comment: Thanks! Works almost perfectly, except when I run it the plots are one-below-the-other instead of side-by-side. I can replace op <- par(mfrow = c(2, 2)) with layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,4),ncol=2,byrow=FALSE)) and it works exactly right. Thanks again!

Comment: Oh, when I replace plot(fm) with plot(summary(fm)) the code no longer works. It seems the two plot functions ignore par() and draw in the same place. My results are only visible when I use plot(summary())... any thoughts on how to fix it?

Comment: Have added `plot.summary.rqs` as well so now the example shows both.

Comment: Regarding your comment about `mfrow` note that `mfcol` also exists.