# (R) Plotting quantile regression coefficient distribution with quantreg package

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple plots with high-level plotting functions, especially plot.rqs()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660614/multiple-plots-with-high-level-plotting-functions-especially-plot-rqs)

I'm running 18 quantile regressions with one dependent and one independent variable. I want a $6 * 3$ tile plot of the distributions of the 18 slope estimates across $\tau = 0.01,0.02,...,0.99$.

Here's what I've been able to do so far:

```
require(quantreg)

op <- par(xlab="")
y=rnorm(200)
x=rnorm(200)
plot(summary(rq(y~x,tau=1:99/100)),parm=2,main="",mfrow=c(6,3),mar=c(0.5,2,2,2))
par(new=TRUE)
plot(summary(rq(y~x,tau=1:99/100)),parm=2,main="",mfrow=c(6,3),mar=c(0.5,2,2,2))
```

The second plot goes all the way to the bottom right, and when I try a third time it's not even in the graph window.

I've tried to put the par(mfrow=c(6,3)) outside of the plot() but it didn't work.

[image]

Comment: There are 50 or more warnings. What shows up when you type warnings() ?

Comment: It's just "`In rq.fit.br(x, y, tau = tau, ci = TRUE, ...) : Solution may be nonunique`".  Happens all the time doesn't matter what variables you're using. It's from `rq()`, not from `plot()`.

Comment: @DWin My data is the `y` and `x` that I generated in the code that I supplied.

Comment: I don't think you can use `par` statements in the plot statement. What does `parm=2` do?

Comment: @smillig You can use `par` when you're doing a `rq` object (see quantreg documentation). `parm=2` plots only the slops estimate and ignores the intercept when plotting. Works perfectly for normal plots but apparently not for `mfrow` tiled plots.

Comment: see the top answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660614/multiple-plots-with-high-level-plotting-functions-especially-plot-rqs).

Comment: Sorry for the earlier comment. I didn't understand the underlying functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default behavior of plot.summary.rqs is to construct a tile plot with one plot for each parameter, which may be what you have been accustomed to seeing, but as Roland says it is using par() in a manner that defeats your efforts. You can overcome this a couple of ways. One would be to redo the function. But if you want to leave the function unchanged, you could just make an auxillary function (a copy of the original with a new name) that comments out the par calls (there are 2) and use it for your subsequent plotting within the framework.

[image]

Comment: I've tried to create a new function that's identical to `plot.summary.rqs`, with the only difference being (following what you said) that both instances of `par(mfrow = mfrow_orig, mar = mar_orig)` were commented out with `#`. Then I copied your code (with par(new=TRUE) in between each call) and the first call of the new function made a graph that took up the whole graphical device (instead of being small and adhering to my desired `mfrow`).

Comment: No need for the `par(new=TRUE)`. Notice I did not use it in my screenshot. The layout gets populated one by one after it gets set up by the first call. I think the `new=TRUE` will overwrite the first plot and defeat your purpose.

Comment: I tried it first without `par(new=TRUE)` and it didn't work. Let `plot2` be a function that's identical to `plot.summary.rqs` in every way except for the fact that the two `par(.....)` rows have been deleted. Then I run the four lines --- Line 1: `y=rnorm(200)`, Line 2: `x=rnorm(200)`, Line 3: `plot(summary(rq(y~x,tau=1:99/100)),parm=2,main="",mfrow=c(6,3),mar=c(0.5,2,2,2))`, Line 4: `plot2(summary(rq(y~x,tau=1:99/100)),parm=2,main="",mar=c(0.5,2,2,2))`, and there will be a graphical device window with one plot and no tiling as I want with `mfrow`.

Comment: My apologies. I realize now I had commented out the second par() call in making a modified copy of `plot.summary.rqs` so that it would not restore the original par settings. So I now have a `plot.summary.rqs` with the second `par(.)` commented out and one `plot2.summary.rqs` with both `par` commented out. ( And use no `new=TRUE`).

Comment: Any idea how to suppress the x-axis in these? No option for `xaxt` or `axes` in function argument.

Comment: You can add an `,xaxt=NULL` argument to the argument list and `,xaxt=xaxt` to the plot call in the function and then `xaxt="n"` in the console call.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would worry about those warnings.

The problem is that `plot.summary.rqs` sets and resets the plotting parameters, which is not nice imho. One solution would be to define your own plotting function based on `plot.summary.rqs` without this feature.

Comment: (1) I'll give that a go, thanks. However, I will wait for a few more days in case someone knows because so many papers do the tiled plot and I can't see anyone complaining on R forums so it's probably the way I'm coding it. (2) `(1:99)/100` is the same as `1:99/100`.